# not displaying the selected initial view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

i selected one view controller in my app as the initial view controller. However, when I run the program, it displays another view controller. I am 100% sure that I checked the right box. I also created a new storyboard and copied everything over to compile again, but still doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea?? Thanks!

Comment: Is the controller that was presented in the same storyboard?

Comment: show your project settings and storyboard

Comment: How about the little arrow thing, is that pointing to the correct view controller?
"Stoyboard Entry Point"

Comment: @DarthMike yes the presented view controller is in the same storyboard.

Comment: @GabrielPires the arrow points to the selected initial view controller but it isn't being displayed